# How to make a development flask server easier to start?

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing some backend code in a flask application and would like to make it easier for the front end developer start it locally so he could test the app and change front.. I would like that it was possible for him to just execute a file that downloads all the requirements and starts the server.. Can I use virtualenv of my machine on his one so he don't have to download everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm following this  [tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world), he is complete from hello world to deploy your application.